# Function issue with buttons only working in certain order

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to this. My app below works but for some reason the buttons only function in a certain order. For example, when I press the send email, it won't function. But if I press the sms and cancel the option then press email, it will work. This is extremely problematic for new installs.

The app works functionally but the buttons only work in certain order.

```
package com.example.travel
import android.Manifest
import android.Manifest.permission
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*


private val MY_PERMISSIONS_LOCATION = 101
private val MY_PERMISSIONS_SMS = 105
private val  MULTIPLE_PERMISSION = 110

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    requestPermissions(
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
        MULTIPLE_PERMISSION
    )
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permission is not granted
    }


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permission is not granted
    }
```

// Here, thisActivity is the current activity

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {

        // Permission is not granted
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this,
                permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
        ) {

        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_LOCATION
            )
        }
    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted
    }

    fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            MY_PERMISSIONS_LOCATION -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                }
                return
            }

            // Add other 'when' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
            else -> {
                // Ignore all other requests.
            }
        }
    }



    button4.setOnClickListener {
        val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:+Enter Phone Number")
        startActivity(callIntent)
    }

    button5.setOnClickListener {
        val intent2 = Intent(this, privacyActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent2)
    }


    val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback


    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.


            fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


                locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                        locationResult ?: return
                        for (location in locationResult.locations) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var lat = location?.latitude
            var lon = location?.longitude
            var acc = location?.accuracy



            button.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + "Enter Phone Number"))
                intent.putExtra(
                    "sms_body",
                    "I have reached my destination." + " My location is: " + "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon
                )
                startActivity(intent)

            }
            button2.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + "Enter Phone Number"))
                intent.putExtra(
                    "sms_body",
                    "I am in immediate need of assistance, " + " My location is: " + "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon + " Accuracy:  " + acc
                )
                startActivity(intent)

                button6.setOnClickListener {
                    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                    emailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:Enteremailaddress")

                    emailIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Safety Check-in")
                    emailIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I have reached my destination" + " My location is: " + "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon);
                    try {
                        startActivity(emailIntent)
                    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()

                    }

                    button3.setOnClickListener {
                        val emailIntenthelp = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                        emailIntenthelp.data = Uri.parse("mailto:Enter Email")
                        emailIntenthelp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "URGENT ASSISTANCE NEEDED")
                        emailIntenthelp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "I am in need of immediate assistance" + " My location is: " + "Latitude: " + lat +  "Longitude: " + lon)
                        try {
                            startActivity(emailIntenthelp)
                        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of your code is a hint to your problem. You only set the `OnClickListener` on `button6` after the `OnClickListener` on `button2` has been executed. The `OnClickListener` on `button3` isn't set until the `OnClickListener` method of `button6` has executed.

You need to make sure that you put the calls to `setOnClickListener()` all outside of the methods. This should look like this:

```
            button2.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + "Enter Phone Number"))
                intent.putExtra(
                    "sms_body",
                    "I am in immediate need of assistance, " + " My location is: " + "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon + " Accuracy:  " + acc
                )
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            button6.setOnClickListener {
                val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                emailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:Enteremailaddress")

                emailIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Safety Check-in")
                emailIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I have reached my destination" + " My location is: " + "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon);
                try {
                    startActivity(emailIntent)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                }
            }
            button3.setOnClickListener {
                val emailIntenthelp = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                emailIntenthelp.data = Uri.parse("mailto:Enter Email")
                emailIntenthelp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "URGENT ASSISTANCE NEEDED")
                emailIntenthelp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "I am in need of immediate assistance" + " My location is: " + "Latitude: " + lat +  "Longitude: " + lon)
                try {
                    startActivity(emailIntenthelp)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! One other challenge. when the app requests permissions to use the services, if the user allows them, none of the buttons will work until the user closes the app and reopens it. Then everything works as planned. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume that your calls to `setOnClickListener()` are not being made in the case where the permissions are granted. You should debug your app and set breakpoints and single step it to see what is happening.